# FileInputStream read method keeps returning 194

Tags: java

I'm teaching myself Java IO currently and I'm able to read basic ASCII characters from a .txt file but when I get to other Latin-1 or characters within the 255 range it prints it as 194 instead of the correct character decimal number.

For example, I can read abcdefg from the txt file but if I throw in a character like © I dont get 169, I for some reason get 194. I tried testing this out by just printing all chars between 1-255 with a loop but that works. Reading this input seems to not though... so I'm a little perplexed. I understand I can use a reader object or whatever but I want to cover the basics first by learning the byte streams. Here is what I have though:

```
InputStream io = null;
        try{
            io = new FileInputStream("thing.txt");
            int yeet = io.read();
            System.out.println(yeet);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Which encoding do you use when you save or create the file? Which editor do you use to save or create the file? Or do you create the file from the java application itself?

Comment: For the encoding I'm not sure what you mean but the file extension is .txt As for the editor im using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Use a `FileReader` for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some solutions for you.

**The first solution** 
There is a full understanding of the book on this [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

**The second solution**
I have a sample code for you

```
public class Example {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String str = "hey\u6366";
      byte[] charset = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
      String result = new String(charset, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Output:

> hey捦

Let us understand the above program. Firstly we converted a given Unicode string to UTF-8 for future verification using the getBytes() method

```
String str = "hey\u6366";
byte[] charset = str.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Then we converted the charset byte array to Unicode by creating a new String object as follows

```
String result = new String(charset, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

You can see here that HEX code for `©` is `c2 a9` i.e. `194 169`. It seems that your file has [Big Endian Endian Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and you read the first byte which is `194`.

**P.S.** [Read a file character by character/UTF8](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_character_by_character/UTF8#Java) this is another good example of java encodings, code-points, etc.

Comment: Thaaat's a tad bit confusing for me. Why is it giving me that rather than 169?

Comment: `Big-Endian` instead of `Little-Endian`.

Comment: Very interesting! Besides the wiki do you know how I can learn more about this? The book I'm reading doesnt seem to cover it

Comment: This is the basics of file encoding. End Wiki covers it: just WORD (two bytes) could be written `LO-HI` or `HI-LO` and you have to know it when reading the file with data. Usually, `LO-HI` (i.e. Little-Endian order) is used.

Comment: UTF-8 byte sequences are not affected by endianness. U+00a9 is always C2 first A9 second. OTOH for UTF-16, big-endian is 00 A9 and little-endian is A9 00, with no C2 anywhere.

Comment: I have looked into the endianness thing, but my confusion is now: Why does this come into play for a byte higher than 127 but lower than 256? That falls within the size of 1 byte(0-255) so why is endianness needed for this rather than just representing it as 169 as 1 byte than 2. As far as I know the write method accepts an unsigned byte so...yeah

Comment: Look at *Signed number representations* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations). When you write a byte you could treat it as a signed or unsigned value.